# Kotlin getOrPut oddness

Tags: kotlin

The following function (`f1`) computes a Fibonacci number as expected:

```
fun f1(n: Int, map: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf(Pair(0, 0), Pair(1, 1))): Int =
        map.getOrPut(n) {
            val a = map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f1(n - 1, map) }
            val b = map.getOrPut(n - 2) { f1(n - 2, map) }
            a + b
        }
```

but this version, `f2`, returns only 0,1 values:

```
fun f2(n: Int, map: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf(Pair(0, 0), Pair(1, 1))): Int =
        map.getOrPut(n) {
                    map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f2(n - 1, map) }
                    +
                    map.getOrPut(n - 2) { f2(n - 2, map) }

        }
```

It looks like `f2` takes only the first "branch": `map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f2(n - 1, map) }` and not the second.
I know that `f2` can be fixed as like this:

```
fun f2(n: Int, map: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf(Pair(0, 0), Pair(1, 1))): Int =
        map.getOrPut(n) {
            (
                    map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f2(n - 1, map) }
                    +
                    map.getOrPut(n - 2) { f2(n - 2, map) }
            )
        }
```

Why are `(..)` required ?

**Edit**

As explained by @user2357112 and @emerssso, it is a case of incorrectly inferred semicolon, the following works as expected

```
fun f2(n: Int, map: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf(Pair(0, 0), Pair(1, 1))): Int =
        map.getOrPut(n) {
                    map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f2(n - 1, map) } +
                    map.getOrPut(n - 2) { f2(n - 2, map) }
        }
```

Not cool.

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin guy, but that sounds like semicolon inference after `map.getOrPut(n - 1) { f2(n - 1, map) }`. It was a bad idea in Javascript, and it doesn't sound like it's any better in Kotlin.

Comment: After further research (and finding [a relevant blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/why-i-missed-semi-colons-today-e2fb136f58e5)), I'm pretty sure this is semicolon insertion. I have also found that Kotlin semicolon insertion appears to be almost completely undocumented. Seriously, what the heck, JetBrains.

Comment: The example in the blog you linked to looks quite similar. *And* moving my + one line up fixes the issue.

Comment: @user2357112 why don't you reply and collect the points?

Answer (score 4):

This is because Kotlin is inserting a semicolon after the `+`, and mapping `+` to [the unary plus operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-plus.html) instead of the normal two-argument plus operator that you would intuitively expect.

You can confirm this by doing a Go To Declaration (Command+click on a mac) with it structured as in your question. It takes me to unary plus with your formatting, and normal plus with parentheses added or no newlines.

The result of this unintended semicolon is that it will recurse down the Fibonnacci generation, but never do any addition, silently always returning the result of only the `getOrPut(n-2)` step (as it's the last statement in the function).

Comment: Whoops, was happily tinkering with this in IDE and didn't see the chat. Looks like we reached the same conclusion.